# PL/SQL select the minimum value of a vector

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table that looks like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tip_orase AS VARRAY(10) of VARCHAR2(50)
/
CREATE table excursie_try (
 cod_excursie NUMBER(4),
 denumire VARCHAR2(20),
 orase tip_orase,
 status varchar2(20)
);
```

And i need to find out 'cod_excursie' of the entry that has in orase the lowest number of entries.

I can do this with a lot of work by counting for each entry the number of cities and selecting a minimum. Then making a query to give 'cod_excursie' of the entry that has the lowest number of entries in orase.

Is there a simpler way ? I tried something like:

```
select cod_excursie 
from excursie_try, (select max(orase.count()) m
                     from excursie_try) T
where orase.count = T.m 
  and ROWNUM <= 1;
```

but it does not work. Any ideas or i have to take the LONG way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select cod_excursie from (
  select et.cod_excursie, 
         (select count(*) from table(et.orase)) n
  from excursie_try et order by 2 desc
) where rownum = 1;
```

`(select count(*) from table(et.orase))` is a single-row subquery, I used TABLE to emulate sql table on varray.

`order by 2 desc` in the subquery + `where rownum = 1` is used for top-N reporting.

Comment: perfect :D thank you very much! i had no idea you could do that table(et.orase), very nice feature!